# Comparing categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I'm comparing two groups in a large dataset. For some of the variables, the following 5 choices are available: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or more

This seems like categorical data- but would it be considered ordinal or nominal? Can I just use the 5 choices on their own to compare across groups, like doing a chi squared analysis and regression models? Or should I be doing any sort of dummy coding or watching out for anything else?

EDIT- the data is ordinal. one of the questions, for example, is # of arrests. how would I proceed if I want to compare across groups like in a regression model? dummy code?

Comment: You need to make the decision on the first question. For example, country, race,.. are nominal; level of pain, degree of like/dislike are ordinal. The following questions depend on the answer to the first question.

Comment: it would be ordinal data then

Comment: Then use Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel chi-square test.  I do not think you need model, given there is no other covariate.

Answer (score 0):

It solely depends on your data. If they are just simple answers to some kind of multiple choice questionnaire, i.e. they can be replaced by $A$,..$E$ or can be shuffled, they are nominal. In this case, you should employ some sort of coding to use them, like one-hot. If they represent some kind of degree, e.g. movie ratings, votes etc. then the variable is ordinal and applying a transformation could be fatal.

Comment: yes, they represent some degree. one question for example is # of arrests